# Comparing Weighted Coins

Tags: statistics

Suppose we flip two different weighted coins each $n$ times. The first coin comes up heads $a$ times, the second coin $b$ times. When can we reject the null hypothesis that the coins are weighted the same? (Say, with $p<\varepsilon$).

---

To be clear, this is *not* a homework problem. I'm trying to derive a statistical test I need in my research. I have phrased the problem in terms of coins for ease of asking.

Here's where I am at:

Of course I know the coin flips follow a binomial distribution. So if we let $A$ and $B$ be random variables for the number of heads of each coin, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the weights for each coin, then we have

$P(A=a) = {n \choose a}\alpha^a(1-\alpha)^{n-a}.$

I think I want to find the probability that the difference between $A$ and $B$ is the same or more extreme than in the observation, assuming $\alpha = \beta$. If that probability is less than $\varepsilon$, I will reject the null hypothesis.

So I write $p=P(|A-B| \geq |a-b|) $, but I don't know how to proceed because the value of $\alpha$ is unknown. (This is unlike the classic case where we test if a single coin is fair.)

Comment: We're not supposed to just do your homework for you, we're just supposed to help you get past the point where you got stuck.  So show us your work and what exactly is hanging you up.

Comment: Please reconsider your downvote, as this is not homework, and I have added my thinking and shown where and why I am stuck.

Comment: I hadn't downvoted it, but I gave it an up now

Comment: There is a statistics website in the stackexchange group, Cross Validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the likelihood ratio test to calculate the p-value, as in this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Coin_tossing